# Websocket Dropped Frames?

Tags: audio, tcp, websocket, digital-ocean, vonage

Trying to solve a perplexing issue w/streaming audio over websockets. We are using Nexmo (Twilio competitor) which enables bidirectional streaming of call audio over websockets. Nexmo connects to our websocket server and starts sending 16khz sampled audio frames of length 640 bytes each.

Everything was working great until recently the websocket audio suddenly started dropping clumps of frames, resulting in gaps in the audio.

But the most interesting thing is the following:

1. When Nexmo connects directly to our digitalocean vps, frames are dropped
2. When Nexmo connects via an ngrok tunnel, everything starts working again

Any ideas on where to look for a real solution would be awesome.

Comment: did you resolve the issue? I cannot figure out any solution. I do not have high CPU  or memory usage but Nexmo all of the sudden stopped working so I am not hearing anything anymore calling my Azure Web App... ngrok sometimes works, sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Make certain the process which is receiving the websocket traffic has a separate thread just to handle this traffic ... any system will drop traffic if its too busy with other tasks ... if your receiving end has some event loop its maintaining while getting preempted by incoming websocket interrupts you will drop packets

I did a project where receiving end was the browser which was running an event loop to perform the audio rendering while simultaneously also handling the websocket traffic - not a good idea since the critical portions of this event loop must not be allowed to get preempted ...  I had to create a webworker process on browser side to handle all the websocket traffic to then populate a circular audio buffer ... this webworker was viewed as a client by the browser event loop which was rendering the audio yet was now permitted to never get preempted by incoming traffic ... only when browser event loop reached its lull period did it then request to retrieve another gulp of data buffered up by webworker audio buffer queue